# Laravel how to set post route ID?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to edit some stuff from mysql and post again.

My blade post open with:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' => '/admin/servers/bans/edited']) !!}
```

Route:

```
ModuleRoute::post('admin/servers/bans/edited/{id}', 'AdminServersController@bans_editToDb');
```

But i'm getting error **NotFoundHttpException**. That's wrong? I think it's because i did not setup form open id? Thanks for helping me understanding laravel!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['/admin/servers/bans/edited', $id]]) !!}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Seems really weird. I'm getting **Undefined variable: id** but in controller id setuped. `public function bans_editToDb($id)`

Comment: Do you pass the `$id` to the view?

Comment: @MyndeMindaugelis i think you pass Model to your view, replace `$id` to `$YOUR_MODEL->id`

Comment: Thanks guys! U made me on the right way. I do something like that: `$serverbans->id = DB::table('server_bans')->where('id', $id)->first()->id;` and seted `{!! Form::open(['url' => ['/admin/servers/bans/edited', $serverbans->id]]) !!}` now works thine. Does it good or not? :)

Comment: @MyndeMindaugelis `$serverbans->id = DB::table('server_bans')->where('id', $id)->first()->id;` replace to `$serverban =Serverban::where('id', $id)->first();`